# Add content rule based on the form field value input data in Plone?

Tags: python, plone, ploneformgen

I create a form using PloneFormGen.eg.
Product code: Gear-12
Value       : 2000

Based on the input value i.e if Value is >5000 , move the saved data content entry to folder 1 else move the entry to folder 2.

How can the TALES expression be used to trigger this kind of content rule? 
I am using Plone ver 4.1

Comment: @Wooble based on the value input on the form, I wish to save the data entry to a folder called 'approved cost' based on quotations from various vendors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to do this, you need to create 2 content rules--each with different conditions and destination folders to move the content to(using the "move to folder" action).

In the content rules, add a TALES expression condition. Then do something like:

> python: request.form.get('value-to-check', False) == 'foobar'

Obviously, you'll need to customize the expression a bit.

Comment: Tooo Goood ya ... @vangheem you are a genius